# ScrollView scrolls under other content

Tags: java, android, layout, scrollview

How can I prevent the ScrollView from scolling content under the LinearLayout content?
ScrollView just uses all the display space and I can't limit this.
Tried with main Relative- and LinearLayout.

My code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/your.app.package"
    android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image"
    android:onClick="openImage1"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/loading"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems kind of weird to me that you have a RelativeLayout inside your scrollview..  but if I'm understanding your question correctly, you want the scrollview to be underneath the upper LinearLayout that you have there.  I'm guessing you're looking for something like the following:  (Take a look at the new `LinearLayout` that I added, and the `android:layout_below`.  I also changed the outer layout to a `RelativeLayout`;  again, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I hope this is helpful in some way.)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <LinearLayout
   xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/your.app.package"
   android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/below_ad_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_below="@+id/ad_layout" >
   <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image"
    android:onClick="openImage1"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/loading"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#000000" />

   </RelativeLayout>
   </ScrollView>
   </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hey i had given margin bottom for small image, in scroll view default linear layout having large data, So this linear data is overlapped the image, for bigger screens that is not the issue. for small screen this is a issue(4" screen is issue)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted your entire XML code; I can only guess that these elements are both contained within a `LinearLayout` with `vertical` orientation.

To get the `ScrollView` to fill all space not taken by the `LinearLayout`, use `layout_weight`.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
```

Comment: its contained within a RelativeLayout

Comment: Ah, well, in this case you may want to switch layout types, since you don't want the two to overlap. Is there something keeping you using `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: i changed it now to linear layout, but i get error message "invalid lyout param in a LinearLayout: layout_centerHorizontal", samefor layout_below

Comment: Remove those two attributes from the `ScrollView`, then. It should automatically be below the `ad_layout` anyway...

Comment: well u can can see my change in my updatedfirst post, but the problem still exists